# Java IntelliJ 13.1.4 "Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

When I try to use the expression `value -> value` I get an error that says that Lambda is not supported. I am currently using the 1.8 JDK with Lambda support, but I still get the error. My guess is that it is IntelliJ 13.1.4 but I'm not positive.

```
public static void grades(){
    final List<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int gradelistnumber = 1;
    int inputedgrade = 0;

    while(inputedgrade != -1){
        System.out.println("Enter Grade for student " + gradelistnumber + " (1-50): ");
        inputedgrade = sc.nextInt();
        grade.add(inputedgrade);
        gradelistnumber++;


    }

    System.out.println("Class Average: " + System.out.println(grade.stream().mapToInt(value -> value /*error*/).sum()));
  }

}
```

Comment: It should say your Intellij Version number on the application title bar.  If not, you can find it in `Help -> About`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In addition** to `File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language Level` as other has mention,
you should also check `File > Project Structure > **Modules** > Sources > Project Language Level` and set to 8

Answer (score 8):

Go to

```
File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language Level
```

Check if it is 8.0

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the wrong language level this line of code also has compile error (the `+` operator cannot be applied to `void` returned by `System.out.println`).

```
System.out.println("Class Average: " + System.out.println(grade.stream().mapToInt(value -> value /*error*/).sum()));
```

Change it to:

```
System.out.println("Class Average: " + grade.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum());
```

And as for the language level, you can change it a little more easily than going into *Project Structure* menu. Just position your cursor to the part of the code which shows error, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and select *Set language level to 8.0*

This is in general a good thing to keep in mind, because in IntelliJ you can easily resolve a lot of warnings and errors from the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> menu.

Answer (score 3):

Fix maven compiler plugin if you build your project with pom.xml

```
   </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SnmpAgentExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Same can be done with gradle with this [properties](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html):

```
compileJava.sourceCompatibility
compileJava.targetCompatibility
```

And also check as previously mentioned.

> File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language Level